# Set instance variable param value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters

I am learning rails and have run into bump.

I have a view that contains the following:

```
<span><%= @goals.cost_per_conversion %></span>
```

(just as an example while `@goals` actually contains more then just cost_per_conversion)

Under certain circumstances the view will not have the instance variable `@goals`. I am trying to guard against cases when this is true.

In my controller I have the following code:

```
if Goal.exists?(params[:id])
   @goals = Goal.find(params[:id])
else
   @goals.cost_per_conversion = 'N/A'
end
```

Naturally this returns an error as `.conversions` is not a method.

How do I set the conversions param so that my view can still work when there is no `@goals` variable available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`#try`](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/try) :

```
<span><%= @goals.try(:cost_per_conversion) %></span>
```

And change the controller code :

```
@goals = Goal.find(params[:id])
```

Double checking record in controller is expensive. Btw, since it's a single record, you could name it `@goal` instead of `@goals`.

Comment: in this case however @goals is not a single record. but your previous answer was perfect and this applies as well! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use `if`:

```
<% if @goals %>
    <span><%= @goals.cost_per_conversion %></span>
<% end %>
```

and change the controller code to:

```
if Goal.exists?(params[:id])
   @goals = Goal.find(params[:id])
end
```

or

```
if params[:id]
   @goals = Goal.find(params[:id])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider creating a new Goal object with `@goals = Goal.new` in case the goal could not be found in the database.  Or you could make a null object that acts like a goal, following the [null object pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).

These are just two ways to approach it, and are not necessarily better than the other answers.

By the way, since your instance variable just contains one goal and not a collection of goals, it should be named `@goal`.